# How to implement appsecret_proof with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am trying to implement appsecret_proof to my web app. I am using PHP SDK. I searched on the internet for some solutions, but there are confusing info. Some pages say you only need to set your app Settings/Advanced/Security/ Require App Secret to yes and and PHP SDK will automatically send 'appsecret_proof' with the call, but others say you have to add 'appsecret_proof' as a parameter to a call. What is the true?

If I have to add a parameter to a call, how can I add it to this

`$graphResponse = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,email,picture');`
  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but others say you have to add 'appsecret_proof' as a parameter to a call. What is the true?

The easiest way to get proper, reliable information on issues like this, is always to check the official documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/ says:

> If you're using the official PHP SDK, the appsecret_proof parameter is automatically added.